# If each $(X_i,T_i)$ is finite and discrete, then the box product is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

**If each $(X_i,T_i)$ is finite and discrete, then the box product is not compact.**

Let each $(X_i,T_i) = \{x_i\}$, then the box product is only covered by the open set $U = \prod \{x_i\}$, but since this is also the finite subcover for the box product, it is compact.  This seems to be a contradiction to the first statement.

Could someone explain to me what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: If each space is a singleton then the product is a singleton, which is clearly compact.  The theorem should say something like each space has more than one point.

Comment: A hypothesis is missing: there must be infinitely many indices $i$ such that $|X_i|>1$.